# How can I get the variant of the language on ios?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have my Iphone set to English (UK) and I am trying to get the UK part in my flutter ap by doing this.

```
final languageCode = Platform.localeName.split('_')[0]; //prints en
final countryCode = Platform.localeName.split('_')[1]; //prints NL where I want UK
```

But my country code is alway NL which is my region. How can I get UK?

[image]

Comment: Can you access the native `Locale.autoupdatingCurrent` property? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale The Locale object has the language code as well as utility functions to extract dialect

Comment: I didn't see anything in the flutter locale class https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Locale-class.html and I don't think I can get to Locale.autoupdatingCurrent from what I could find.

Comment: There must be some way to build native Swift or Objective C code into a flutter app.

Comment: is [languageCode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Locale/languageCode.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: I got the same issue, Flutter can't read the region if there is a brace with location behind the language on iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its look like you want to access ISO Country Code

You can acces your device language country code with :

```
//Your device's all locales
final List<Locale> systemLocales = WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.locales; 
//Your device's first(current) locale country code.
String? isoCountryCode = systemLocales.first.countryCode;
```

Comment: The region will be ignored when the languages followed by braces with a location, e.x. in this case, won't get `NL`

Comment: does this support IOS right?

Answer (score 0):

Following are the 3 ways I know to get locales:

```
Localizations.localeOf(context);
WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locale;
Platform.localeName;
```

Make sure to have the `supportedLocales` correctly setup in your `MaterialApp` which is only en_US by default, in order to have all available locale.

```
supportedLocales: [
     const Locale('en', 'UK'),
     const Locale('fr', 'CA'),
],
```

You may need to import and add to your pubspec.yaml `'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';`